# Still having Java install problems

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Please review my script, all I want to do is check to see if a particular Java Verison is installed (latest version) if it is not installed, then to go to the install command...

Having problems with the For /F command though.

PLease see what I have so far:

```
@echo On
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"
set VALUE_NAME="BrowserJavaVersion"

FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
set ValueValue=%%A
) 
if defined ValueValue (
@echo the current Java runtime is %ValueValue% 
) else (
@echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found
```

This is the key I am trying to interrogate from within the Windows Registry (BrowserJavaVersion):

!http://i393.photobucket.com/albums/pp11/Mikoyan_2008/Screenshot.jpg

If the version doesnt match latest Java version to then:

if "%ValueValue%"=="Latest Java Version" ( goto eof ) ELSE ( goto Install )

Can anyone please provide assistance?

Comment: Your code is fine. You just forgot to close the If statement with a `)`

Comment: @Matt                                                               Doh! Thanks :) I get 2 outputs if I run the script (not sure how I can implement a IF EXISTS or query the version to say, something like: IF %VALUEVALUE% = latest Java Verison i.e. 10.51.2 Go to End Else run Install Script? I am really stumped on the interrogation and ERRORLEVELS for for/f

Comment: `for /f` doesn't have an `errorlevel`. The commands contained within it do. Read `for /?` carefully and notice that if you put it all on the same line, you only use 1 set of parens.

Comment: Thanks Matt for clearing that up, have managed to get the script working now :)